# jQuery elements created using .append(html) not available

Tags: jquery

I have the following

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mapLink").click(function(){
            pos = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(pos);
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="map" id="test">Test</a>
```

When I click on Test I get an alert...great.
But I also have the following...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mapLink").click(function(){
            pos = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(pos);
        });
    });
    $(#emp").change(function(){
        $("#existingAttendTime").html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "existingAttendTime.php?emp=" + SelValue + "&time=0",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#existingAttendTime").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="mapLink" id="test">Test</a>
<div id="existingAttendTime"></div>
```

When the  emp changes it fires off and gets the results from existingAttendTime.php and inserts it into the div, so now it looks something like...

```
<a class="mapLink" id="test">Test</a>
<div id="existingAttendTime"><a class="mapLink" id="12345">Return Test</a></div>
```

Clicking on Test gets me the alert "test", but clicking on Return Test gets me nothing.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: I think you have an error in Test. You seem to be referencing .mapLink and you have it listed in the html as .map for the css class.

Comment: Jeeze, thanks all - sorry I can't accept all the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind your click handler in 'live' mode, or else newly-added DOM nodes won't trigger it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mapLink").live("click", function(){
        pos = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(pos);
    });
});
```

There used to be a plugin required for live queries, but jQuery 1.3 integrated a limited version of it [into core](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live). Also note that only some event types work; `change`, `submit`, etc. will not, so you would have to explicitly attach the handler inside the same function that appended the new node to the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Event handlers are attached on DOM ready *once*, if you manipulate the DOM you will need to either

- A) manually reattach event handlers
- B) rely on jQuery.prototype.live

It's probably more suitable to use B, so I suggest changing your click code to something like..

```
$("a.mapLink").live("click", function(){
    var pos = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(pos);
});
```

This will target any anchors that have been added through DOM manipulation.

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

And FYI you should be using var to declare `pos` in the current scope.

Answer (score 2):

When adding items dynamically, the `click` handler will not be registered on the new items. Instead, use `.live()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mapLink").live('click', function(){
        pos = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(pos);
    });
});
```