# How do I bind a "data appended" event in js / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment, I have a piece of code looking like this:

```
$("#somediv").append(data);
somethingToDoAfterDataAppended();
```

It seems that the data is appended asynchronously, therefor the next function is not necessarily invoked after data is actually appended.

I was thinking about a way to bind this function with 'data appended' event - is it possible?

Any other solution would be equally useful.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068955/jquery-function-after-append

Comment: Or also [this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)?

Comment: `.append` is always synchronous. Whatever the problem is, it's somewhere else. Try to reproduce the issue in a live scenario.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. It is synchronous, it was my mistake of invocation placing. Again. sorry, thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, I'd remove my downvote but I can't if you don't edit the question (or post an answer with the solution you've found).

Answer (score -1):

It simple. You can change the append method and insert there a trigger(s) for you special event.

```
$.fn.append = (function(old){
   return function(){

       $(this).trigger('beforeAppend'); // if needed
       var result = old.apply(this,arguments);
       $(this).trigger('afterAppend');
       return result;

       }

    })($.fn.append);
```

Somewhere in your initialization logic:

```
$("#somediv").bind('afterAppend',somethingToDoAfterDataAppended);
```

And :)

```
("#somediv").append(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, same behavior.