# Apply iCheck (jQuery plugin) to dynamically created CheckBoxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, icheck

I use the fantastic [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) plugin to style my checkboxes in my form.

With the plugin, I am able to just call `$('input').iCheck()` to apply the desired look and functionality.

However, I am stuck at calling the `.iCheck()` function on dynamically created checkboxes.

In an ajax call, I build my checkboxes as follows in the success function; This is in an `$.each` block but for simplicity purposes, I've only included code within the statement.

```
var chk = $('<div><input id="' + n.ID + '" type="checkbox" name="lblChk"><label for="' + n.ID + '">' + n.Title + '</label></div>');
el.append(chk);
```

Where `el` is a div with the id of `container` that already exists in the DOM tree and `n` is my object returned as JSON

After building the checkboxes and I call `$('#container input').iCheck();` obviously I get nothing special but standard checkboxes. I presume it is because the checkboxes are created dynamically and after the `.iCheck()` is called. But even after I create checkboxes and call `.iCheck()` the result is the same.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: See the bottom answer and comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068955/jquery-function-after-append. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Yatrix thanks for the response but which answer are you mentioning? Is it the one with the setTimeout() option??

Comment: Womi's at the bottom of the page

Comment: Yeah, but that is a very dirty solution. You do not know when the ajax call will complete, hence calling setTimeout which happens to get called before the success or complete event is a risk I do not intend to take :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? If not, could you please provide the complete code?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
$('#container').iCheck({checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'});
```

Answer (score 7):

Also there is another situation ... when iCheck has Callbacks

This code won't work for the ajax-loaded inputs, since it's a replacement of bind():

```
$('#mycheckbox').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
    alert();
});
```

Delegated events should be used instead:

```
$(document).on('ifChecked', '#mycheckbox', function(event) {
 alert('done'); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
$('#container').find('input').iCheck();
```

have you tried checking length of `$('#container input')`? I am not sure but input is not the direct child of `container` so might not be found with selector `$('#container input')`.

Comment: `$('#container input')` selects each `<input/>` inside `#container`, no matter if it is a direct child. Direct children would be selected the same like in css with `$('#container > input')`.

Comment: what if I have an ifToggled Callbacks attached to each input ... how do I initiate that also ???

Comment: @Florin can you elaborate more? or better ask separate question if you have different scenario. cant see anytihng related to ifToggled in question. ...
if its some kind of event... see live() or on() methods in Jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had a similar problem sometime ago and solved it like this:

Assuming that the `el` variable is a jQuery element I'll bind the plugin iCheck's initialization to the `el`'s fully  load, so:

**This code should be placed after AJAX appends data**

```
el.ready(function() {
  $('#container input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green' // If you are not using radio don't need this one.
  });
});
```

Remember to adapt the code to the particularities of your HTML structure. Running the above code just after the elements are appended to the page you are initializing the iCheck of these newly added elements, however if you are using the iCheck callbacks, the plugin will only work if you declare these callbacks correctly, delegating the events to the appropriate tags just as [Florin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1830139/florin) warned.

**This code should be placed on the iCheck first initialization**

```
$(document).on('ifChecked', '#mycheckbox', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(document).on('ifUnchecked', '#mycheckbox', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input').iCheck({
     checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
     radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
});
```

if you want to set from specific div try this:

```
$('#MyDivId input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
});
```

Check the documentation on http://icheck.fronteed.com/

Comment: Avoid 'try this' or 'try that'. However, show some example with fiddle is a good idea

Answer (score -2):

I just encountered the same problem and the solution is simple: call the iCheck method.

```
var id = some_id;
var one_row = "<tr><td>...<td><td><input type=\"radio\" class=\"minimal\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\">radio1</td></tr>";
// add this row to HTML
// call the initialize method
$('#'+id).iCheck({radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue'});
```