# jQuery 3.0 $(window).load(function(){});

Tags: jquery

so jQuery 3.0 was released today, and for some reason the following code no longer works on my site:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

Can anyone suggest how I fix this or an alternative that actives when /everything/ is loaded?

Comment: Have you read the [changelog](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/)?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon What would be the .on() equivalent of my code?

Comment: `$(window).on('load', function(){})`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Reading from [breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed):

> Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed
>
> These methods are shortcuts for event operations, but had several API limitations. The event .load() method conflicted with the ajax .load() method. The .error() method could not be used with window.onerror because of the way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach events by these names, use the .on() method, e.g. change $("img").load(fn) to $(img).on("load", fn).

Therefore, you need to change:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

to:

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {})
```

Comment: I did change it to `$(window).on('load', function (e) {})` on version 3.1.1 but its still not working

Comment: I found that using single quotes after `on` making it to fail, I've changed my code to  `$(window).on("load", function (e) {})` now its working, I don't know why quotes do matter.

Comment: Ok now its not firing on either one

Comment: @developer Please, click on the javascript tool and choose wrap the js into the head instead to run it onLoad. The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce284bmu/1/).

Comment: Why do I have to wrap on head?

Comment: @developer If you run it on OnLoad  the window on load is already executed. Instead if you wrap it into the head section you say to jQuery: run it on dom Load. It's up to you. You may use the standard jsfiddle.net feature and so you need to remove the window on load or you can handle it by yourself wrapping the code into the head section.

Comment: Thank you very much. ;) enjoy your Overflow on the Stack :))))

Comment: @developer You are wellcome