# How to set element CSS proportional height with JQuery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set the heights of elements with a specific class via JQuery to a 16:10 ratio via their width, however the height is not applied, it remains at the minimum pixel height set in CSS:

JQuery:

```
function makehorizontal() {
$('.horizontaled').each(function(i, obj) {
var myWidth = $(this).width();
var myHeight = myWidth/1.6 + 'px';
$(this).css('height', myHeight);
});
}
$(window).load(function() {
makehorizontal();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
makehorizontal();
});
```

CSS:

```
.image-background-holder{
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height: 20px;
position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image-background-holder horizontaled" id="box-1"></div>
<div class="image-background-holder horizontaled" id="box-2"></div>
```

Comment: when does it happen? on dom ready or/and window resize?

Comment: both, on document/page read and resize, no change. it remains at min. css height

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I noticed, it was the JQuery version. 3.3.1 was not working, 2.1.0 is working, strangely ... but why ??

Comment: [jQuery.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751179/jquery-3-0-window-loadfunction/37751413#37751413) is your issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem can be solved by using `min-height` css instead. You might also consider setting `max-height` if you want to maintain the ration even if the content would not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working as expected... try verifying your css properties precedence, or can use min-height instead of height

```js
function makehorizontal() {
$('.horizontaled').each(function(i, obj) {
var myWidth = $(this).width();
var myHeight = myWidth/1.6 + 'px';
$(this).css('min-height', myHeight);
});
}
$(window).load(function() {
makehorizontal();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
makehorizontal();
});
```

```css
.image-background-holder{
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height: 20px;
position:relative;
}

#box-1{
background:red;
width:160px;
}
#box-2{
background:blue;
width:160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-background-holder horizontaled" id="box-1"></div>
<div class="image-background-holder horizontaled" id="box-2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! it turned out, it was the new jquery 3.3.1 version that broke the code. I had to change $(window).load(function() {}); to $(window).on("load", function (e) {});