# how to append with content and afterAppending function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

default jquery append only support `.append( content [, content ] )`, how to implement following code:

```
$(body).append("<p>prpr</p>", function() {
// do smth after append
})
```

Comment: basically you are requesting a callback?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068955/jquery-function-after-append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't think you you need a callback, `.append()` DOM manipulations is synchronous. so just put the function below the `.append()` line

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can check `$(element).length` to make absolutely sure that the new DOM nodes have been appended.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $('body').append('<p class="newParagraph1">This is a new paragraph, added via a script.</p>');
  
    $('body').append('<p class="newParagraph2">This is a second new paragraph, added via a script.</p>');

    if ($('.newParagraph1').length) {
console.log('The first dynamically added paragraph just loaded.');
    }
  
    if ($('.newParagraph2').length) {
console.log('The second dynamically added paragraph just loaded.');
    }
  
    if ($('.newParagraph3').length) {
console.log('The third dynamically added paragraph just loaded.');
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This paragraph is already in the markup</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").each(
    function(){
        $(this).append("<p>prpr</p>");
        function() {
                // do smth after append
        }
    }
}
```